# Is possible to interpret and operation on string using a mathematical function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, math

I want to select the final value of a string (for example `'3+4'`) using a SELECT. I want to know if exists a function or a way in MySQL.

Example:

```
SELECT ('4+1*3') as VALUE;
```

The result is:

```
VALUE
7
```

Comment: you can't pass this as a string in query.

Comment: This is very much not what a database engine is for. You've also tagged this question as PHP; I'd strongly recommend performing any evaluation in that instead, probably before the expression reaches the database in the first place.

Comment: what you are trying to do may be possible, but is just *wrong*. there is no valid reason ever to do this. do your PHP-calculations *in* PHP.

Comment: Maybe.... however, if your columns are numerically named, then that's an issue and requires to be handled in a special way. Not quite sure what you want to do here, yet again "why".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three steps:

1. Combine query into a single string
2. Create a prepared statement from this string
3. Execute said statement

Something like this:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT (', '4+1*3', ') AS VALUE');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Note that this does not merely evaluate mathematical expressions. A malicious user could insert pretty much anything into the query here, so you are open to the worst of sql injection attacks unless you carefully sanitize the string you paste into the query to only allow mathematical expressions.

Note that I can think of no application where this kind of operation would be useful. I'd say if you have to evaluate arbitrary strings, you're probably better of doing so in application code, not in the database.